# combining dataframe columns into two dimensional matrix

Tags: r

Is there a simple way to transform this dataframe into the form below? I thought I could just get the desired column and cast it to a matrix, but that didnt work.

```
set.seed(1)
data1<-data.frame(dv=rep(c("low","high"),3),iv1=rep(c("A","B","C"),2),freq=runif(6))
as.matrix(data1[,3],ncol=3) #this didnt work
```

GOAL:

```
#     A   B  C
#high .28 .32 .39 
#low  .31 .36 .31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
xtabs(freq~dv+iv1, data1)
```

Or

```
library(reshape2)
acast(data1, dv~iv1, value.var='freq')
```

Or

```
with(data1, tapply(freq, list(dv, iv1), FUN=I))
```